# Expo push notification handle onPress action

Tags: react-native, expo

i have react native expo project and i am looking to implement push notifications. I am building a ordering app and after the user places an order, i want to notifiy then to leave a review.

Currently everything is working in terms of the notification getting displayed and the onPress action i can listen too but not able to do navigate to a new screen.

This is my Stack Navigator:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


const HomeNavigator = ({navigation}) => {

  const notificationListen = (notification)=>{
    const {type} = notification?.request?.content?.data ?? {};

    console.log('notification listen type',type)
  }

  const responseListen = (notification)=>{
    console.log('responseListen',notification)

    const {type} = notification?.notification?.request?.content?.data ?? {};


    console.log('notification response type',type)

    
//     if(notification&&type==='order'){
//   Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'My Alert Msg', [
//     {
//       text: 'Cancel',
//       style: 'cancel',
//     },
//     {text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Welcoome')},
//   ]);   
//  }

  }

  useNotifications(notificationListen,responseListen);

return(
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen}/>   
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
)}

export default HomeNavigator;
```

I keep getting navigation is undefined.

I have also found online that navigation.navigate('Welcome') only works with Stack Screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `navigation is undefined` error is because you're trying to use navigation in the callback function of the `useNotifications` hook. At that point, the component that defines the navigation prop is not rendered yet, and hence the navigation prop is not available.

To solve this issue, you can create a `navigationRef` using the `NavigationContainerRef` provided by `React Navigation`. Then, you can pass this `navigationRef` to the `NavigationContainer` component as a prop. This will allow you to access the navigation object outside of the components, including inside the callback function of the `useNotifications` hook.

```js
import { NavigationContainerRef } from "@react-navigation/native";

...
...
...

export const navigationRef = React.createRef<NavigationContainerRef>();
```

```js
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
  {/* rest of your code */}
</NavigationContainer>
```

In your `responseListen` callback function, navigate to the Welcome screen using the `navigationRef`:

```js
if (notification && type === "order") {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate("Welcome");
}
```

You'll need to import the `navigationRef` in your component that defines the `Stack.Navigator` and wrap it with the `NavigationContainer`.

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { navigationRef } from "./navigation";
import HomeNavigator from "./HomeNavigator";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <HomeNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```